# Working with Pagination (Selenium webdriver C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a problem while automating my test for Pagination.
My code is able to iterate through table on first page and also able to click the Next page if 'Search Element not Found'. But, the problem is that for the second page it is not holding/getting the data of table. Although Class of table used is static for all pages.
Please Help me through this. Here's my chunk of code:

```
IWebElement pagingInfo = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Dj")); //Getting text from Page info in the form of  "1-emailsPerPage of totalNumberOfEmails"
string[] stringArray = pagingInfo.Text.Split(' ');
int totalNumberOfEmails = Convert.ToInt32(stringArray[2]);
int emailsPerPage = Convert.ToInt32(stringArray[0].Substring(2));
int clickCount = totalNumberOfEmails / emailsPerPage;

for (int i = 0; i <= clickCount; i++)
{
    IWebElement tableInbox = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Cp")).FindElement(By.ClassName("F"));
    IList<IWebElement> rowsCollection = tableInbox.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

    foreach (IWebElement row in rowsCollection)
    {
        IList<IWebElement> columnCollection = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        if (columnCollection[5].Text.Contains("Fwd: Security"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Record found");
            recordFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (recordFound == true)
        break;
    webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ar5")).FindElement(By.ClassName("amJ")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}

if (recordFound == true)
    Console.WriteLine("Record Found");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Record Not Found");
```

Please Help!! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: N what's the error u get?

Comment: I am not getting any error its just when i run my test in debug mode then for the second page, no Text is present for tableInbox and hence unable to search for desired string (Element not Found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the page is using Ajax so i have to use iFrame for navigating through the same table for each page.
Using iFrame solves my purpose.
The problem is finally solved after a lot of research. :)